# Is there any advantage of pushing branches to GitHub without an associated PR?

Tags: git, github, branching, pull-requests

I work with other Software Engineers on a web app product. Also, the source code is hosted on **GitHub**.

There is a behavior pattern that I do not understand. Some co-workers push branches (adding features or fixing bugs) as **standalone branches**, without an associated Pull Request.

I do not understand this behavior. I can see some disadvantages.

- For instance, CI scripts with automation and build tests will not run on these standalone branches, but only on branches submitted associated with Pull Requests.
- Another disadvantage is that standalone branches do not have a comment/review GUI section to discuss the code as Pull Requests have in GitHub.

But, maybe I am missing something on the advantages of this practice.

Is there any advantage of submitting a standalone branch adding a feature or fixing a bug without converting the code into a Pull Request submission?

Comment: If these branches are longer lived, you get to keep a copy of the code safely stored in the cloud if your drive fails? (And you make the code available to others if you, like, take sick days or something).

Comment: What happened when you asked your co-workers why they do this?

Comment: I haven't asked @PhilipKendall.

Comment: @PedroDelfino I think he's being coy, and that's kind of the point. You should ask.

Comment: Why is this question with multiple comments upvoted and an answer upvoted multiple times being downvoted?

Comment: @PedroDelfino Because you haven't explained why you haven't done the really obvious thing and asked your coworkers why they do this.

Comment: If they cannot see any advantage of doing it your way, then why do it?  So the question that you need to address is, why does pull requests bring value to your way of working?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, I mentioned the disadvantages in my question.  The advantages are the opposite. Unlike standalone branches, PRs can have CI scripts checking them and they have a nice GUI for comments and discussions.

Comment: @PedroDelfino  Not for _us_, for your _coworkers_! Have you asked them?

Comment: @PedroDelfino Have you asked your coworkers yet _and if not why not_?

Comment: @PhilipKendall. No, not yet. I am shy.

Comment: @PedroDelfino man up and get them talking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Small features / bugfixes can be added, tested, pushed, and a PR created all within a short time span - maybe a couple of hours. In those cases, there's not much reason to push a branch without creating the PR. If you lose the work, it's not all that much effort to recreate it.

For larger changes, though, pushing to the server provides a second copy of the work-in-progress code. The work is not done, so it's not appropriate to create a PR. However, this second copy provides a backup in case your computer dies. It allows others to see - and continue - your work, in case you're out sick, go on vacation, get hit by a bus, etc. It allows others to start building off your work, if needed (not recommended, but sometimes unavoidable). It also allows you to access the code from different computers (maybe one in the office, one while working from home), which may be beneficial depending on your workflow.

I'm sure there are other reasons as well, this is not an exhaustive list.

Comment: If the work is not ready, why not creating a PR draft?

Comment: What's the actual benefit of creating a PR draft? Maybe they don't expect it to build yet and there's no point running CI.

Comment: also, just sharing the code, asking for help etc

Comment: @PedroDelfino - "If the work is not ready, why not creating a PR draft?" - well, maybe they are not ready for code review yet, and don't want to bother people. Maybe they are pushing to that branch every 10-20 min. Maybe they want to merge in someone else's changes and resolve conflicts before making the PR. People work in different ways. You can create a PR from the branch later.

Comment: @PedroDelfino I do it because I don't want to pollute my draft PRs timeline with tons of spam push/force-push events. Those spammy events aren't wiped when the PR is published as ready-to-review, so it just adds needless noise. I create a draft PR when I'm actually ready to solicit early feedback from coworkers.

Comment: Real life story.. we had a developer who worked on a feature for about 4 weeks.  Then they disappeared, basically ghosted the team.  No remote branch.  All work was not recovered.  We had to start over.  That promised feature was not delivered in that cycle.  If they had pushed to a remote branch we could have taken what was done and continued it and finished.

Comment: > "pushing to the server provides a second copy of the work-in-progress code"

This is true, but probably a backup tool provides an easier way to do this. It can easily be automated to make a second copy of anything every day.

Comment: People use branches purely as a backup. If my machine breaks down, everything on a remote branch is backed up. And what @JonRaynor said: If his developer had not left but his hard drive broken down, they would have had the same sad situation.

Comment: @PedroDelfino: PR drafts run the risk of being approved and merged before they're finished - unless you explicitly make sure that it can't, until edited to be made not a draft - at which point, the spammy events  Alexander mentioned have likely made it harder to draw attention to the PR when it's ready for review. You could also run a test run of the code on staging to verify if it's good enough to be in a PR, while building it out, if you can get staging to use your temporary non-stage branch in a specific temporary instance.

Answer (score 2):

> For instance, CI scripts with automation and build tests will not run on these standalone branches, but only on branches submitted associated with Pull Requests.

That depends on how you have your CI set up. You can run builds on every branch push, *if you want to*.

> Another disadvantage is that standalone branches do not have a comment/review GUI section to discuss the code as Pull Requests have in GitHub.

Well, that's the point, isn't it? If someone *wanted* to start that discussion, they would create a PR. Since they didn't, we can infer that they had something else in mind. Maybe they're just moving from one machine to another and they need somewhere to stash their work-in-progress. Maybe it's a staging area for aggregating changes from other branches. Maybe it contains an experiment, or a reproducer for a bug, which is useful to show someone else, but which doesn't pass tests and isn't ever intended to be merged.

Github is still git, and git still supports a lot more workflows and usecases than the "make a PR and merge it" one.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like I should first address some apparent premises that this kind
of question is based on.

Being able to share code to a remote repository that multiple people
have access to (read-write or just read) is the bread-and-butter of
repository-based Git workflows[1] that involve more than one person. That’s
very powerful in itself.

In fact, it’s the foundation on top of which all the forges (like
GitHub) are built.

So turn the question on its head: do you need the forge-exclusive stuff?

Yes, they’re powerful as well. In particular being able to comment on
individual lines is very convenient.

But they *are* extras that you don’t need on every occassion.

It’s like git(1): a suite of commands (maybe a hundred?), but on most
days you might only use a handful.

---

Some use-cases:

- Someone asked you about something you are working on right now, so you
  push the branch for them to see what it’s about
- Two of you are working on something related, so you agree that the
  other person will base their work on top of your branch
- Someone else had a nice temporary workaround for an issue that you
  also are having, so they push a branch which you can temporarily
  rebase or cherry-pick into your branch as temporary commits (to be
  removed later) so you can get back to whatever you are working on
- You have some changes that doesn’t need a PR to review. You agree with
  two other people that they are going to merge it into the main branch
  after being able to look at the diffs and playing with it in their own
  local repositories

  - You DM them that you pushed a branch to the repository instead of
    *both* pushing a branch and making a PR

#### Postscript

There’s value in appreciating the “basics” and how you can get quite far
with just one suite of tools (like what git(1) is) without relying on
something else (GitHub can be used as a code hoster without any of the
GitHub-extra stuff).

#### Notes

1. Meaning workflows where you coordinate your work through either one
   shared remote repository or via multiple. This is not a standard term
   or anything.